# Microsoft Mail for AppleTalk

Tags: mac-os-classic, microsoft

I want to tinker a bit with Microsoft Mail for AppleTalk, Version 3.1. I installed the System Extensions, they get loaded and the server itself shows up in the chooser with it's serial number.

To administer the server, I need to log in as some kind of administrator. Different sources (also alert dialog boxes when starting the administration program) hint to a "network manager" but it's not clear if this is an actual login or just a description. Besides that, I can't find a reference which default password to use. Not surprisingly, since I'm talking about Software from 1992.

Does any of you dear readers remember how to sign into the server via the accompanying desk accessory, so I can utilize the admin program to set up stuff?

Comment: After carefully watching the error message when trying to log on, it is indeed "Network Manager". This yields "Wrong password", whereas any other user name yields "Unknown user".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Username is indeed "Network Manager", the password is "mail". Tried a few things and got it by chance.